# object particle system not transfering with object

Tags: particles

i have an object(tree) that uses a particle system (leaves). but when i try to spread the trees with another particle system on a plane, the leaves don't carry over with the tree[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a special modifier called "Particle Instance" in order to use nested particles. I'll link the blender docs :

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/simulate/particle_instance.html

And an up-to-date tutorial on Youtube :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpvNJvsq-FU&